# BLENDER 2.8 TEXTURE PAINT

Tags: modeling, texture-painting

I made a low poly model, uv unwrap it, go to texture paint, apply all scales, set a diffuse texture but can't paint on the model only on the uv. 
Also where did the color picker go in 2.8?

Comment: Tools are in the properties panel under the little wrench and screw driver icon. Try to add painting slot there. There will be everything familiar.

Comment: Actually I did add a painting slot. The only weird thing is that I separated the model. I made a bird decoy with a base. It seemed easier to separate the base from the bird to simplify texturing. I tried again with a new model made from scratch and everything seems to work ok. When I separated the model by loose parts it didn't seem to work at first but they did become separate objects.

Comment: So I repeated the problem. If I make a model , uv unwrap, go to texture paint I can freely paint on the model and the uv image panel. If I make a model and separate it into two objects I can only paint on the uv panel not the model itself.

Comment: In this case i can paint only on the active object (outlined with yellow) not on every selected object. But if I make active the another in object mode, then go back to text paint mode I can paint on it. But everytime I able to paint one of them. If you can't paint any of them it's probably a bug.